# How to responsively position images diagonally (react)

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, grid, gsap

I originally created a diagonal slider using the viewport width and height to determine where each box/image needed to be both on the x and y axis. However, when I started implementing animations the performance started to suffer. This is due to the window size being a dependency of a useEffect.

I am curious to know if there may be a better approach to spacing out the items diagonally that doesn't cause a re-render when the browser window resizes. Would grid or possibly flexbox be a better route or possibly something else. I've linked my sandbox below.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-butterfly-zot2xe?file=/components/Images.js

Animated Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-spence-m52t2p?file=/components/Images.js

Comment: What do you mean by diagonal slider?  In the sandbox, I only see 3 static images.  What are the animations you mentioned?

Comment: @jme11 I took out the animations to simplify the sandbox. I've added another sandbox below the original with all the animations. Just scroll or click on another image and it will animate

Comment: You could get CSS to do most of the work for you by usiing say grid and rotating its container. JS would be needed just to set up the required angle.

Comment: @AHaworth when you say 'rotating its container' do you mean the grid container or the individual container of each image?

Comment: I mean the element that contains them all (which is the one with grid display if you are using grid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of **slope**. Slope is the incline of a line, which is being conducted by 2 points (a line segment, rather).

Now, the first thing that I see in your question is:

> responsively

Usually when we are dealing with responsive stuff we use percentages, because they automatically adjust on resizes etc. So we know that `m = rise/run`, `m` being slope. Let's say you wanted your slope to be `-2`, for example.

Your coordinates would be (starting at `[0, 0]`):

```txt
[0, 0]
[2, 1]
[4, 2]
[6, 3]
[8, 4]
```

***NOTE: I DID NOT USE NEGATIVES BECAUSE `[0, 0]` IS ON THE TOP LEFT, THERE ARE NO NEGATIVES.***

Comment: I think I've been using slope the whole time without actually realizing it. Since Im just using gsap's x and y (short for translateX and translateY) and the index of each image. I guess I thought I could have a one size fits all solution to make it responsive on all viewport sizes. I think using media queries and relative units may be the best option.

Comment: Hi,I don't really understand how this is a complete answer, or how using media queries would help when the viewport aspect ratio (and hence the slope) can be anything. Is it possible to have a snippet which demonstrates the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can get CSS to do much of the work for you by placing the items in a grid and rotating that diagonally.

A continuous flow of items can be obtained by having two copies and transforming the slider just 50% of its length rather than the full 100%.

A bit of JavaScript is needed initially to work out what angle the slider should be at - this depends on the height and width of the viewport.

This snippet recalculates the angle on a reload or a resize. After that JS is not involved and the system should be able to optimise the use of processor power, for example by leaving the transformation to a GPU.

```js
function init() {
  const container = document.querySelector('.container');
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
  const w = window.getComputedStyle(container).width.replace('px', '') / 2;
  const h = window.getComputedStyle(container).height.replace('px', '');
  const rad = Math.atan(h / w);
  container.style.setProperty('--rad', -rad + 'rad');
  container.style.setProperty('--cols', items.length);
}
window.onload = init;
window.onresize = init;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: translateY(calc(50vh)) rotate(var(--rad));
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200vmax;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols), 1fr);
  display: grid;
  animation: move 20s linear infinite;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-size: 50% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  transform: rotate(calc(-1 * var(--rad)));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="item" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300);">
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/300);">
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1018/300/300);">
    </div>
    <!-- second copy of the items -->
    <div class="item" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300);">
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/300);">
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1018/300/300);">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok this kinda makes sense. Your initial comment and this answer gave me another direction I'm currently exploring. I will update this thread if I get it to work. Thanks for the help